# iOS: Orientation check rotation on ViewDidAppear

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, rotation, orientation

**Background:** I want to make sure my viewControllers rotate properly when it appears. My viewControllers have excellent codes managing the rotation and orientation when it is visible.

**Problem:** Given two viewControllers in a NavigationController, `viewC1` and `viewC2`. I did the following:

1.) Set rootViewController to `viewC1`

2.) Push `viewC2` into the NavigationController

3.) Rotate

4.) Pop `viewC2`

5.) `viewC1` is still stucked in the old orientation look (as in the transformation code in  `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` was not called) with the new orientation.

What can I do to ensure `viewC1` call `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` to reconstruct itself to look correctly in the new rotation?

**Additional info:**
This is all code (no storyboard/xib). I have `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` return `YES` on all the views. I use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` to manage all my rotation.

Oh, and please no hacks. For example, copy the code from rotation then check the rotation mannually and manage it in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Don't call ViewControllers `view1` and `view2`. That's just confusing. There's a huge difference (as you know) between a `UIView` and a `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the name of the method, and what you're trying to achieve.

`willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` indicates that the view controlled by the view controller is about to animate to a particular orientation. If your view is in the middle of a navigation stack, then it is not being displayed on screen. To animate something that isn't on screen is costly and ultimately worthless. So, that particular method is out of the question, but the problem that remains is there isn't anything else more appropriate in UIKit. The reason is to rotate something (even if not animated) when it's offscreen is worthless cost. It's the responsibility of the developer to handle a change in orientation when the view appears ("transformation on demand" as you will).

You say you don't want hacks, but the method you've described as a hack is probably the most appropriate thing to do. Having a generic method named something like
`-(void) updateLayoutForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation animated:(BOOL)animated { ... }`
isn't a bad idea. This can be the handler for orientation change transformations for the whole view controller.

The places you need to possibly check/handle orientation issues are

`-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

`-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation duration: (NSTimeInterval) duration`

and in both of these, call `updateLayoutForOrientation:animated:` to do the work for you.

Comment: Valid point argument. Let wait around and see if anyone else has a more direct way of doing it, since it seems rotation with view switching is very common. Unless a better way comes along in a day, I will mark your answer correct. For your information, you can just use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` inside `viewWillAppear` and achieve the same results.

Comment: @Byte Don't get me wrong, calling `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` within `viewWillAppear` is certainly possible. It's my own personal style to extract shared logic and place it in its own method, and have direct delegate methods call that. I feel it makes the code a little bit better to understand, but it all comes down to personal preference.